# Getting Location coordinates of a friend in android

Tags: android

I want to create an application in android like when users get registered themselves to an app. The admin can get the location of all users which get registered. I don't know how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use gps sensor in the android application to get latitude and longitude coordinates... Here is my blog link to get working code.... http://rahulraina09.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-gps-application-programming.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

This android application code (using gps sensor) can help you to get the latitude and longitude (speed and distance as optional) and rest of the things (saving coordinated to main server) you can do yourself.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Location p1=new Location("point a");
    Location p2=new Location("point b");
    double longitude,latitude;
    TextView speedview,xstart,ystart,distance,time;
    float speed,dist;
    LocationManager lm;
    Button b;
    int flag,flag1;
    int hour,min,sec;
    String location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        speedview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.speedview);
        xstart=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.slatitude);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ystart=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.slongitude);
        distance=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance);
        time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wait while device check your position.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        flag = 0;
        flag1 = 0;
        hour = 0;
        min = 0;
        sec = 0;

        lm =  (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Latitude","enable");

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Latitude","disable");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(flag==0)
                {
                    p1.setLatitude(arg0.getLatitude());
                    p1.setLongitude(arg0.getLongitude());
                    flag=1;
                    dist=(float)0.0;
                }

                xstart.setText("Latitude: "+String.valueOf(latitude));
                ystart.setText("Longitude: "+String.valueOf(longitude));
                latitude=arg0.getLatitude();
                longitude=arg0.getLongitude();
                speed=arg0.getSpeed(); 
                speed=(float)((speed*10)/2.55);
                speedview.setText(String.valueOf(speed)+"  kmph");
                p2.setLatitude(latitude);
                p2.setLongitude(longitude);
                dist=p2.distanceTo(p1);
                if(flag1==1)
                {
                   // distance.setText(String.valueOf(dist)+"  km");
                }
                Date date=new Date();

            }
        });

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(flag1==0)
                {
                    flag1=1;
                    flag=0;
                    b.setText("Stop");
                    //to start timer code

                }
                else
                {
                    flag1=0;
                    b.setText("Start");
                    //to reset timer code
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Use android permissions:-

1. `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`
2. `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`